# Location popup still appears after enabling location from notification panel in React Native using 'react-native-geolocation-service'

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, geolocation, react-native-permissions

I am developing a React Native application where I am using the 'react-native-geolocation-service' package to request location permission. When I open the app for the first time and haven't enabled the location, a popup appears with a Settings button, prompting the user to enable the location.

However, I noticed that if I enable the location from the notification panel instead of clicking the Settings button in the popup, the popup message still persists. It only disappears when I click the Settings button and enable the location from there.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Is there a way to handle this scenario properly? I want the popup to disappear automatically once the user enables the location from the notification panel without having to click the Settings button separately.

Comment: Unless react added a second one (unlikely), the enable location dialog is a OS dialog.  You have no control over it.